# Magento setPrice() and setCost() methods

Tags: magento-1.7

What is the difference between the Magento methods setPrice() and setCost()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ste
Magento `setPrice and getPrice are two difference setter function of Magento product Object.`

`setPrice`  is `a most import function of magento product which set  product price generally give  product attribute price value`.

`SetCost is`   a `price type  attribute which used for Quote item used for calculated original of product during cart`

Comment: Can you elaborate this one ($method->setPrice(), $method->setCost()) With real time example..?  In the Shipping amount calculation Used ..?

Answer (score 0):

**setPrice()**: Used to set the price of the shipping method. This is the amount that the customer will see during the checkout process. This value can be set manually or dynamically depending on the shipping method used (Based on the weight of the products in the cart, or other rules that might be set up in Magento).

**setCost()**: Used to set the cost of the shipping method for the store merchant. It's not often visible to the customer. Primarily used for internal calculations, analytics, and reports.

*Real Time Example*:

Let's suppose, you have a shipping method and you want to charge customers $10.00 for it but merchant actually paying $5.00 to the courier service so in this case we suppose to use setPrice(10) for customer and setCost(5) for Merchant purpose.